# Serialize objects with inheritance by defining serialize method only in base class?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I am currently doing a game in C# (for studies purpose). I'm trying to implement a Load/Save feature, which consist of saving every data of the game in a file, and the user can be able to reload the game saved after.

In the game I have a nation class attached to each players, and every nation inherit from `Nation`. For the moment, I have only apply the `ISerializable` interface on the base class, `Nation`, because subclasses only have method override and no new attributes to serialize.

```cs
[Serializable()]
public abstract class Nation : ISerializable 
{
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // save attributes
    }

    public Nation() { } // default constructor, to be able to do "new NationDwarf()" for example.

    // Deserialization constructor.
    public Nation(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        // retrieve attributes
    }
}

public class NationDwarf : Nation {
    // some methods override
}
public class NationViking : Nation {
    // some methods override
}
```

The saving seems fine. But when I'm trying to retrieve data with this method (unserialization), I get an exception (the first player has a NationDwarf):

> SerializationException
>
> The constructor is missing for deserialize an object of type 'SmallWorld.NationDwarf'.

So, my question is : do I need to specify **for each** subclass that it's serializable and redefine each method (`GetObjectData` and the constructor) ? Is there a way to keep polymorphism and serialize every subclass, and of course be capable to get the correct type at deserialization?

I didn't find any solutions, except redefine the serialization method on each subclass, which is a bit heavy...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to provide the serialization constructor and make the GetObjectData virtual in the base class so you can override it in the child classes.

```
public NationDwarf(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    : base(info, context)
{
}
```

While the ISerializable interface is passed on from the base class, the runtime still needs to know how to make an instance of the derived class specifically.

Answer (score 4):

Short version: yes. If you implement ISerializable then your implementation should be virtual and overridden by every (and again: every) subclass.

Options:

- use BinaryFomatter, implement ISerializable, and do that
- use BinaryFormatter but don't implement ISerializable
- don't use BinaryFormatter

I dont mind saying that I usually advocate the last option. BinaryFormatter has... kinks. Personally I'd use protobuf-net, but: I'm biased (I'm the author)

Comment: I understand your choice. But here, it's just for a small (and first C#) project, don't want to deal with third parties for a minor feature :) So I'll define each constructor, as @Mike Johnson explain. +1 anyway, thanks.